# Sublime Text Build Systems variables

Tags: sublimetext3

The [docs](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for Sublime Text Build Systems state:

> you can use some variables in build systems too, as we have done above
>   with `$file`, which expands to the active buffer’s filename.

Are there more variables other than `$file` and if so where can I learn about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are under the [reference section](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#build-system-variables). Here is a current listing of supported variables:

> `$file_path` - The directory of the current file, e.g., C:\Files.
>
> `$file` - The full path to the current file, e.g., C:\Files\Chapter1.txt.
>
> `$file_name` - The name portion of the current file, e.g., Chapter1.txt.
>
> `$file_extension` - The extension portion of the current file, e.g., txt.
>
> `$file_base_name` - The name-only portion of the current file, e.g., Document.
>
> `$packages` - The full path to the Packages folder.
>
> `$project` - The full path to the current project file.
>
> `$project_path` - The directory of the current project file.
>
> `$project_name` - The name portion of the current project file.
>
> `$project_extension` - The extension portion of the current project file.
>
> `$project_base_name` - The name-only portion of the current project file.